# Estilizar fundo do autocomplete

Tags: css, input, autocompletar

O fundo do *input* é transparente, mas quando o navegador completa automaticamente, ele fica com essa cor mostrada na segunda imagem, existe alguma forma de deixar completado, mas que continue transparente? Tentei de várias maneiras, mas nenhuma funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O mais perto que consegui chegar foi [nisso](https://jsbin.com/yatanaxido/edit?html,css,output). Quando autocompletado, o fundo passa a ser transparente.

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!

Comment: Eu não respondo porque foi na tentativa e erro baseado em vários sites. Eu não tenho domínio sobre o que fiz. Se fizer sentido e alguém souber o que está acontecendo no código, sinta-se a vontade para postar como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz alguns testes com o nome `transparent` e caso atribua esse valor ele sempre vai ficar com essa cor padrão do navegador. O mais recomendado é você colocar a cor do fundo, no seu caso, creio que **black**.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px black inset; /* aqui muda sua cor do fundo */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ccc; /* Cor do texto */
}
```